# C# List.Remove(object)

Tags: c#, list, xna, windows-phone

I have an object which is a `List` within a `List`:

```
public List<List<MyObject>> Grid { get; set; }
```

I have noticed that sometimes when I do:

```
Grid[currentShape.ColumnNumber].Remove(currentShape);
```

It removes two objects from the array.

The way in which I populate the `Grid` object is if a certain condition is met, then I basically do:

```
Grid[newShape.ColumnNumber].Add(newShape);
currentShape = newShape;
```

`currentShape` is a class variable which I use to move around the object on the screen. Is it because of a Reference Type that when I sometimes do `.Remove()`, it deletes more than one object from the array? Do I need to extend the `.Remove()` somehow?

Any help is highly appreciated.

**Update** - The entire method:

```
    public void MoveIfPossible(MoveDirection direction)
    {
        List<Shape> neighbouringShapes = new List<Shape>();

        switch (direction)
        {
            case MoveDirection.Right:
                if (currentShape.ColumnNumber == utilities.columns.Count - 1)
                    return;

                neighbouringShapes = GetNeighbouringShapes(currentShape.ColumnNumber);

                foreach (var s in neighbouringShapes)
                {
                    if (currentShape.Position.X + 1 < s.Position.X && currentShape.Position.Y + currentShape.Texture.Height >= s.Position.Y)
                    {
                        return;
                    }
                }
                world.Grid[currentShape.ColumnNumber].Remove(currentShape);
                world.Grid[currentShape.ColumnNumber + 1].Add(currentShape);

                currentShape.Position.X = utilities.columns[currentShape.ColumnNumber + 1].X;
                currentShape.ColumnNumber++;

                currentShape.Coordinate.X = currentShape.ColumnNumber;
                currentShape.Coordinate.Y = world.Grid[currentShape.ColumnNumber].Count - 1;
                break;

            case MoveDirection.Left:
                if (currentShape.ColumnNumber == 0)
                    return;

                neighbouringShapes = GetNeighbouringShapes(currentShape.ColumnNumber - 1);

                foreach (var s in neighbouringShapes)
                {
                    if (currentShape.Position.X - 1 > s.Position.X && currentShape.Position.Y + currentShape.Texture.Height >= s.Position.Y)
                    {
                        return;
                    }
                }
                world.Grid[currentShape.ColumnNumber].Remove(currentShape);
                world.Grid[currentShape.ColumnNumber - 1].Add(currentShape);

                currentShape.Position.X = utilities.columns[currentShape.ColumnNumber - 1].X;
                currentShape.ColumnNumber--;

                currentShape.Coordinate.X = currentShape.ColumnNumber;
                currentShape.Coordinate.Y = world.Grid[currentShape.ColumnNumber].Count;
                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: The documentation states that only the first will be removed. Most likely you are calling Remove twice.

Comment: I am not calling .Remove() twice. I'm only calling it once.

Comment: @Subby - be very sure about that. Put a Debug.WriteLine()  in there. This looks like it might be an event firing multiple times.

Comment: The whole class has only got 1 occurance of `.Remove()` and that's in the above code. So I'm no way calling it twice.

Comment: He's asking if your snippet is inside an event handler - just because you typed `Remove` once doesn't mean the containing method isn't invoked multiple times.

Comment: Internally, Remove() a call to IndexOf() followed by a RemoveAt(). To remove multiple elements, you would have to call Remove() or one of it's cohorts multiple times. How are you determining that more than one item has been removed?

Comment: Instead of arguing, please post the whole code.

Comment: @PrestonGuillot Ah I see. I am calling the `.Remove()` when I am clicking on the Canvas. But as far as I can see, it only runs through the code once.

Comment: I have updated the post to show all the code.

Comment: Guys, I think OP is right. newShape or currentShape are probably referencing multiple items and when it calls Remove, it removes all of them. We need all the code either way.

Comment: Set a breakpoint on the Remove line and see if it gets called twice just in case though.

Comment: Why are you doing currentShape.ColumnNumber++? I'm guessing it has something to do with an off-by-one error between ColumnNumber and coordinates

Comment: Put some Debug.Asserts around the .Add() and .Remove() calls to ensure that the List's count actually increases or decreases by one as expected. My assumption is that you will find that even when you appear to lose two, those asserts will not fire and you will need to look elsewhere in your code for the issue.

Comment: @MillieSmith - he's incrementing or decrement the ColumnNumber because the currentShape instance is keeping track of which column it belongs to.

Comment: I would think that either ColumnNumber or Coordinate.X should be internally set by the other.